# mysql innodb engine next-key lock question under RR

Tags: mysql, innodb

I meet a problem When I learn mysql innodb engine next-key lock (under Reapeatable Read level).

Here is my table structure and table data.

```
CREATE TABLE `o` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `a` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `idx_a` (`a`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

    +----+------+
    | id | a    |
    +----+------+
    |  1 |    1 |
    |  3 |    1 |
    |  5 |    3 |
    |  7 |    6 |
    | 10 |    8 |
    +----+------+
```

I add a normal index to field a and then insert some data.
I start fist transaction(we call trx1) and run following command:

```
mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from o where a=3 for update;
+----+------+
| id | a    |
+----+------+
|  5 |    3 |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I think when I run `select * from o where a=3 for update`,mysql will lock (1,3],(3,6) base on next-key mechanism.
Next,I start second transaction(we call trx2) and run following command:

```
mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from o where a=5 for update;
Empty set (0.12 sec)
```

What surprises me is why did trx2 execute the command `select * from o where a=5 for update` successfully.Because I think trx1 has locked 5 and trx2 will blocking until trx1 commit.

I would be very grateful if someone would answer for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

After few days study,I resolve it eventually.
trx1:`select * from o where a=3 for update;` will lock (1,6) with gap lock.
trx2:`select * from o where a=5 for update;` will lock (3,6) with gap lock.
Gap lock is compatiable with Gap Lock !!! So trx2 won't block.